# Jasper Reports chart on group footer always displays same data

Tags: jasper-reports

I am designing a report with a group called `moneda`. I want each group of `moneda` to display a table and a bar chart, so I added the fields on the detail, and the table is ok, but I also added the chart on the group footer, but all charts display the values of the group's last content:

[image]

This is the code of my report:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.16.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.16.0-48579d909b7943b64690c65c71e07e0b80981928  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ventas_por_cliente" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="35bf9d53-3c13-4b67-97ae-9cf071b2c8fb">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Agroware"/>
    <parameter name="empresa" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="estado" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="fecha inicio" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <parameter name="fecha final" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT
    clientes.nombre_comercial AS cliente,
    divisas.codigo as moneda,
    sum(subtotal) AS subtotal
FROM ventas
INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.id = ventas.cliente_id
INNER JOIN divisas ON divisas.id = ventas.divisa_id
WHERE ventas.estado=$P{estado} AND ventas.empresa_id=$P{empresa}
GROUP BY divisas.codigo, clientes.nombre_comercial
ORDER BY moneda]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="cliente" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="cliente"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="cliente"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="clientes"/>
    </field>
    <field name="moneda" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="moneda"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="moneda"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="divisas"/>
    </field>
    <field name="subtotal" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.name" value="subtotal"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="subtotal"/>
    </field>
    <group name="moneda">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{moneda}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="31">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="340" height="30" uuid="123a2299-31d9-48ca-bce4-943e9fd06cdd"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Cliente]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="c3073fe9-c6be-4a77-8fc1-e3a87a6cd9f0"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Monto]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="480" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="91633715-bad2-4b52-aa01-01d45904d5a6"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Moneda]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="231">
                <bar3DChart>
                    <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                        <reportElement x="7" y="15" width="541" height="200" uuid="74a8cf0f-81b2-48ad-90bf-92b676107457"/>
                        <chartTitle/>
                        <chartSubtitle/>
                        <chartLegend/>
                    </chart>
                    <categoryDataset>
                        <dataset resetType="Group" resetGroup="moneda"/>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{cliente}]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[0]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{subtotal}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                    </categoryDataset>
                    <bar3DPlot>
                        <plot/>
                        <itemLabel/>
                        <categoryAxisFormat>
                            <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                        </categoryAxisFormat>
                        <valueAxisFormat>
                            <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                        </valueAxisFormat>
                    </bar3DPlot>
                </bar3DChart>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="39" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="250" y="0" width="310" height="30" uuid="80541021-385a-4f95-9c7c-209dc89559e6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Ventas por cliente]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="33" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="340" height="30" uuid="cf208f85-7195-451d-9044-d0e8537c7b1f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cliente}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="254feb07-abc2-41b4-bec6-251e782f5985"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{subtotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="480" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="4c323b1a-1455-4f16-a826-dd5e95c6036a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{moneda}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: <chart evaluationTime="Report">, that means it will do it as last task, try with evaluationTime group or Now